# Doctrine: use foreach in a find one

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to use 99% of my code to do two queries.
When accessing api.com/jobs it will display all my jobs, but acessing api.com/jobs/65 will only display that entire job.

My improvement is to have an if before the foreach, to detect whether it is one single id or to list all.

My code looks like this:

```
$Repo = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Models\Entity\Jobs');
if ($param){
  $jobs = $Repo->find($param);
} else{
  $jobs = $Repo->findAll();
}

foreach ($jobs as $j_key=>$job){
  ...
}
```

The problem is: the findAll() is doing great but I can't enter the foreach with the find() only;

Is any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use this approach (I would prefer to separate concerns) put the result into an array;

*edited*

```
$Repo = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Models\Entity\Jobs');
if ($param){
  $jobs[] = $Repo->find($param);
} else{
  $jobs = $Repo->findAll();
}

foreach ($jobs as $j_key => $job){
  // there is a risk that whats in $jobs might not be what you expect. So check.

  if(!$job instanceOf Jobs::class) {
      continue;
  }
}
```

alternatively,  use `findBy` as itll return a Collection object which will iterate.

```
$Repo->findBy(['column' => 'value']);
```

Comment: this is not working: inside the foreach I do: echo $job->getName(); this returns me an error: Error:Call to a member function getName() on integer

Comment: This will try to convert the entity into an array, which will cause each property to be an array key. You will no longer be able to use any methods that were present on the original object.

Comment: This is working, also I tried to test the instanceOf piece of code but gave an error. What really is that for? `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'`

Comment: using `instanceOf` will check that the variable contains a class of that type.  You would use it before assuming that you can call a method of that class to ensure its able to do it.

Comment: youre getting that most likely because of your version of php.. which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having different pieces of code to deal with the two cases but, if you would rather keep them together:

```
$Repo = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Models\Entity\Jobs');
if ($param){
  $jobs = array($Repo->find($param));
} else{
  $jobs = $Repo->findAll();
}

foreach ($jobs as $j_key=>$job){
  ...
}
```

This will create an array with a single element in the case a request is made for a single job, and a request for multiple jobs will return all the matching jobs.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is working but I prefer the @DevDonkey suggestion which is: `$jobs[] = $Repo->find($param);`

Comment: It is good practice to initialise the empty array before you try to assign an element to it in that case. E.g. `$jobs = array()`. See the notes in the PHP documentation: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying